# Ubuntu 9.10 Flashing Cursor during both Desktop and Alternate install

Tags: ubuntu-9.10

I have an Acer Travelmate 230 laptop that i want to install ubuntu 9.10 on, but once i get to the main menu (off the live cd) i select install, and after a progress bar appears for 10 minutes, i just get a flashing underscore. I have left it like this for 3 hours and it doesnt seem to do anything... Is this a hardware fault somewhere along the line? I have ran several Memory and CPU and hard drive tests which all come back OK...

Thanks

Comment: Can you boot from the LiveCD?

Comment: No I just get to the flashing Underscore

Comment: Could you post your PCs specs? Could help to rule/point out possible problems.

Comment: Intel Celeron Mobile 2.00GHz, 256MB RAM.

I think it is my machine because sometimes, it just skips the CD Boot and tries to boot off the hard drive (formatted drive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of troubleshooting tips in the [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/9.10/installation-guide/i386/boot-troubleshooting.html).

Comment: I think it is my machine because sometimes, it just skips the CD Boot and tries to boot off the hard drive (formatted drive). The disc boots on my other machines...